# Converting static JS function with few variables to dynamic

Tags: javascript, object, if-statement, javascript-objects

I am looking for a way to make my JS errors handling function dynamic, now i am checking each possible error seperately, the function code looks like this.

```
function handleErrors(errors){
    
    if (errors.nameError){
        nameEl.classList.add('is-invalid');
        nameEl.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = errors.nameError;
    }
    if (errors.surnameError){
        surNameEl.classList.add('is-invalid');
        surNameEl.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = errors.surnameError;
    }
    if (errors.emailError){
        emailEl.classList.add('is-invalid');
        emailEl.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = errors.emailError;
    }
    if (errors.passwordError){
        passwordEl.classList.add('is-invalid');
        passwordEl.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = errors.passwordError;
    }
    if (errors.passwordConfirmError){
        passwordConfirmEl.classList.add('is-invalid');
        passwordConfirmEl.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = errors.passwordConfirmError;
    }
    if (errors.phoneError){
        phoneEl.classList.add('is-invalid');
        phoneEl.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = errors.phoneError;
    }
    if (errors.addressError){
        addressEl.classList.add('is-invalid');
        addressEl.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = errors.addressError;
    }
}
```

Basically each time i have two variables, i am checking if there exists specific error object and if it exists i am printing that error value to the corresponding HTML element. What would be the way to write a function that would check  all errors dynamically. Thank you for your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like that:

```js
var errorsAndElements = {
    nameError: nameEl,
    surnameError: surNameEl,
    emailError: emailEl,
    passwordError: passwordEl,
    passwordConfirmError: passwordConfirmEl,
    phoneError: phoneEl,
    addressError: addressEl
};

function handleErrors(errors){
    var possibleErrors = Object.keys(errorsAndElements);
    for (var i = 0; i < possibleErrors.length; i++) {
        var errorName = possibleErrors[i];
        if (errors[errorName]) {
            var errorElement = errorsAndElements[errorName];
            errorElement.classList.add('is-invalid');
            errorElement.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = errors[errorName];
        }
    }
}
```

It stores the possible errors and according elements in an object, then it iterates over that object and checks if the error exists in the passed `error` object. If the error exists, it takes the element and displays it.